# How to solve unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' error?

Tags: php, syntax, internal-server-error

How can I fix the error:

> unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' error in line 75?

Does it mean to remove the ';' or ','?

```
$categoryNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($categoryData, 'id', $tree, $parentCategoryNode);
$parentCategoryNode->addChild($categoryNode);

$flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
if ($flatHelper->isEnabled() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true)) {
```

Comment: Usually it means the line before it is missing a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't on `line 75`. Rather, there is a missing `;` or `,` on `line 74`.

There is an "unexpected T_VARIABLE" on `line 75` because of this missing punctuation on the **previous** line.